Question about set theory notation for a set solutions.
Suppose $L_f$ is a constant, and $L_0 (n)$ is a solution as a function of some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
\begin{align}\label{Equation 2}
    L_0 (n) = \frac{L_f}{2^n} \:\:,\:\:\forall L_f, n\in  \mathbb{Z}^+
\end{align}
Since $L_0$ is a positive integer, then $2^n | L_f$. Let $N$ be the set of natural numbers with some upper limit, $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$:
\begin{align*}
    N=\left\{ 1,2,3,\dots ,n \right\} \:\:,\:\: 1\leq n \leq \left \lfloor \log_2 L_f \right \rfloor 
\end{align*}
To test which $m \in N$ (with $1\leq m \leq n$) element values of $2^m$ divde $L_f$, we perform the operation,
\begin{equation}\label{Equation 4}
    \left.\begin{matrix}
    L_f \bmod 2^1 =r_1 \\
    L_f \bmod 2^2 =r_2 \\
    L_f \bmod 2^3 =r_3 \\
    \dots \\
    L_f \bmod 2^n =r_n\\
    \end{matrix}\right\}\in R_N \equiv \left\{ r_1 ,r_2,\dots,r_n\right\}
\end{equation}
defining the set of all remainders as $R_N$.  Let the set, $R_m$, be a subset of $R_N$ such that,
\begin{equation*}
    R_m = \left\{r_1,r_2,\dots,r_m \right\}\equiv \left\{ 0,0,0,\dots ,0\right\} \:\:,\:\: R_m\subseteq R_N
\end{equation*}
for element(s), $r_m \in R_N$, for which the element(s), $r_1, r_2,\dots, r_m$, equal zero. Let $f$ be a function of elements in $R_m$ that yields the desired set of powers, $N_m$, where $N_m \subseteq N$.
\begin{align}\label{Equation 6}
    \begin{split}
    f: R_m  &\to  N_m \\
    \equiv f: \left\{r_1,r_2,\dots,r_m \right\} &\to \left\{ 1,2,\dots,m \right\}
    \end{split}
\end{align}
The set of valid powers, $N_m$, in the growth coefficients will yield the set of solutions, $L_0$.
\begin{align}
    L_0 = \left\{ \frac{L_f}{2^1},\frac{L_f}{2^2},\dots,\frac{L_f}{2^m} \right\}
\end{align}
$\textbf{Question:}$ How can I condense the solution set, $L_0$? Is it correct to simply write $L_0$ as,
\begin{align}
L_0 &= \frac{L_f}{2^{f(R_m)}}=\frac{L_f}{2^{N_m}}
\end{align}
or as,
\begin{align}
    L_0\circ f(R_m)
\end{align}
Please excuse my ignorance on the notation here.

Please abstract your problem into purely mathematical language (eliminate "Damascus blade layers").

Just did. It's an applied math problem with an algorithm that has this short abstraction with set functions.
